# cross compile from Android NDK r25c

Tags: linux, build, android-ndk

Can someone please explain minimally, how to make a cross compiler for armv7-a from Android NDK r25c?

There is, for instance, `./android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi33-clang++` shell script file, but how to build a simple C++ project using a compiler mentioned with this file?

The host machine, is linux 64 bits.

**Note:** I use terminal and don't access to Android studio and Gradle.

**Update:** Reading through [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/BuildSystemMaintainers.md#clang), I made such progress and ran `clang++` on my `*.cpp` file:

```
./armv7a-linux-androideabi33-clang++ src/hello.cpp
```

and get this error:

```
clang-15: error: no input files
```